# How to get current date google fit steps count in laravel using gethealth api?

Tags: php, laravel, google-fit

I Have developed a fitness dashboard. which shows users current day steps count, calories burn, kilometers crossed. for that i'm using gethealth api https://platform.gethealth.io/docs . I can get previous dates data correctly but can't get current date's data.it returns empty array. please give me alternatives for gethealth also.

Followed steps:

step 1: Create account in gethealth and add users using https://platform.gethealth.io/docs/#!/Account_API/CreateUser and store accesstoken in mysql database

step 2: Get devices for added users using https://platform.gethealth.io/docs/#!/Account_API/get_v1_health_user_devices and get connection url from the response. send it to user. with that they can connect google fit with gethealth.

step 3: Get current day activity using https://platform.gethealth.io/docs/#!/Health_Panel_API/post_v1_health_user_daily_summary

```
public function getMembers(){
    $response_arr = array();
    try{
        $members = DB::table('users')
                    ->select('user_id','name','email','role','get_health_id','get_health_access_token','profile_picture')
                    ->where('status','A')
                    ->get();
        
        $curr_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $st_date = $curr_date."T00:00:00";
        $end_date = $curr_date."T23:59:59";
        if(count($members) > 0){
            foreach ($members as $member) {
                $token = $member->get_health_access_token;
                if(!empty($token)){

                $url = "https://platform.gethealth.io/v1/health/user/daily_summary?";

                $get_daily_data_params = array(
                            "access_token" => $token,
                            "limit"        => 100,
                            "start_date"   => $st_date,
                            "end_date"     => $end_date,
                            "source"       => "googlefit"
                        );
                       
                        
                    $params_str = http_build_query($get_daily_data_params);
                    $url .= $params_str;
                    $ch = curl_init($url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

                    $response = curl_exec($ch);
                    $daily_data_arr = json_decode($response,true);
                    curl_close($ch);

                    if(count($daily_data_arr['daily_summary']) > 0){
                        $member->google_fit_data = $daily_data_arr['daily_summary'][0];
                    }else{
                        $member->google_fit_data = "";
                    }
                }
                }
               
            $response_arr['status'] = "success";
            $response_arr['data']   = $members;
            $response_arr['date']   = $curr_date;
        }else{
            $response_arr['status'] = "error";
            $response_arr['message'] = "User Not Found";
        }
        
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $response_arr['status'] = "error";
        $response_arr['message']   = $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $response_arr;
}
```

These steps are i have followed. But i cant get current date's data.
I have also tried sync api https://platform.gethealth.io/docs/#!/Account_API/post_v1_health_account_syncs. but no use.
Please help me.